# What is the antecedent of the pronoun "la"?

Tags: pronoms

In the sentence below, does "la" refer to "un sorte" or "onde"?

> - Ce truc génère une sorte d’onde de choc. La colombe peut **la** ressentir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a metter of meaning, it refers to both, actually. You can't separate "*une sorte*" and "*onde*". **La** refers to "*une sorte d'onde de choc*", it wouldn't make sense to refer to "*une sorte*".

But grammatically, it does refer to "*onde*", as it would be "*le*" with a masculine noun.

Comment: But if "onde" were a masculine noun, would I need to say "le ressentir", referring to the masculine "onde", or need to say "la ressentir", referring to "une sorte"? This is just hypothetical, but in this case I would need to pick "le" or "la".

Comment: Ooh ok, I get your question. I didn't get your question at first, because it makes no sense to refer to "*une sorte*". But yes, the pronoun agrees to the second noun, so you'd say "*une sorte de sandwich ... **le** manger*".

Answer (score 3):

**la** refers to **onde de choc**

> La colombe peut ressentir l'onde de choc.

Answer (score 2):

*La* refers to *onde de choc* and agrees in gender with it.

Should a masculine substantive had be used, *le* would have been required, e.g.:

*Ce truc génère une sorte de **tremblement**. La colombe peut **le** ressentir*